What happens when you target a dead creature with Scrying?
In 5th Edition Dungeons and Dragons, the spell Scrying is described, in part, as follows:

You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw [...]

and also

On a successful save, the target isn't affected, and you can't use this spell against it again for 24 hours.

If the creature you choose is dead, what happens? Can you observe their corpse? Are you barred from using Scrying again with that creature as the target for 24 hours? What, if anything, do you learn about their location and state?

Related discussion on whether a dead creature counts as a creature: Is a dead creature's body considered an object?

Probably requires a separate follow-up question, but there could be some scenarios where it would work if they were raised as an undead, and then it might depend on the type of undead.  Zombie?  probably not.  Vampire, Lich, or Ghost? Sure.  Wight?  Maybe?

A corpse might not be a valid target

You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you. [...]

Corpses are objects. Often, this is ruled as exclusive and that means it is no longer a creature. If the corpse is not a creature but only an object, you can not target the corpse in the first place. As such, the spell fails at the target stage, you don't even get to rolling the save.
Because you chose no valid target, the spell fails and you learn nothing but that your spell failed for any of the many reasons [including, but not limited to: different plane, invalid target, valid target made willpower save, valid target is protected from scrying].
Objects are immune to Wis-saves
Even if ruling that corpses are both objects and creatures, the spell still fails: not in targeting, but because the object has immunity from wisdom saving rolls.
You don't learn the reason
If a spell fails for any reason, the caster just learns that it failed, not why.

Well, you learn something. You learn that the creature you are targeting is either dead or on another plane (or have a really high Wisdom; though I would say its DMs judgement as to whether you can tell the difference between the spell failing due to a successful save and failing to an invalid target).

@PJRZ It is also possible that the target is somehow protected from scrying. As the DM I would narrate this somehow as "You try to magically reach out to [creature] across this whole plane of existence, but for some reason your powers are unable to find them."

@PJRZ Rules don't say you get to learn for what reason your spell failed. There are at least 4 reasons the spell can fail, invalid target is just one of them. But I give you that you do learn that the spell did fail.

@PJRZ Personally I feel casters know the difference between failed to even try and tried but failed.  They don't know why in either vase.

@Trish The question you site supporting your assertion that Corpses are objects actually doesn't say what you are saying here. The accepted answer is silent on whether a corpse can be an object and a creature at the same time, and many other answers support the assertion that corpses are both creatures and objects at the same time.

Corpses are treated as objects, but a dead creature is still a creature, and absolutely must remain so in game terms, or none of the revival spells would work (they all explicitly target dead creatures, not objects.)

@TheFallen0ne they target specifically something, which beats the general

@Trish They specifically target a dead creature. Dead and creatures are both game terms. A dead creature can be used as an object, per RAW rules (see improvised weapons re; dead goblin), but when you use a Hoopak as a ranged weapon, it's still a melee weapon that's valid for any effects that target (or require) a melee weapon. --->  The stance that a creature can be treated as an object has supporting text. The stance that a dead creature uniquely stops being a creature does not exist in any RAW printed text or the SAC, it only exists on this site (and maybe others like it) and in tweets.

It might work, if you are on the right plane
Everyone else has identified the potential issues with targeting a corpse because it's an object, not a creature. However, it's very common within the lore of D&D that creatures who die don't just dissipate into nothing, rather their spirits go to some other plane appropriate to their alignment or deity. In other words, the after life is very real in these worlds.
As such, the scrying probably fails not because you've attempted to target a dead creature, but rather because you probably made your attempt while on the Material Plane and your target is on a different plane of existence.
To that end, if you wanted to Scry upon a creature who was Lawful Evil and elected to do so while you were in the Nine Hells, you might succeed1.

1How the afterlife gets handled is generally subject to DM discretion. So this may not work for your game depending on how the DM views the afterlife.

This is an interesting concept, the only problem with this is that souls go to afterlife, not entire creatures, and they don’t keep their original form, so sure, it might be the soul of your old buddy but now it’s a lemure no. 573645, not your buddy anymore

@AnnaAG this is fuzzy area and has probably been left deliberately vague by the designers to allow for DM adjudication. If you look at True Resurrection, though, you can simply speak a creature's name and they can be brought back in a new body, thus there's some sort of connection to a creature's original existence and whatever afterlife it has.

There is nothing in the rules that says i) what is a soul and ii) a soul is a creature.

@Eddymage I'm aware. Hence why this is subject to DM discretion.

So, it is "it might work if you're DM decide it works", as the DM can overrule everything...

@Pyrotechnical or that, assuming (ii) is true, there's another hurdle: iii) is the soul of a dead creature still the same creature? — The species is wrong, to begin with: the soul of a dead human is not a human.

@MindwinRememberMonica the discussion on this issue prompted me to post a question about this issue here: https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/212234/31402

@MindwinRememberMonica as a side note, I would point out that there is a lot of lore relating to 'true names' for demons and the like. Perhaps that true name is the creature's original name when they were mortal. Thus, might still be a valid target for scrying (and were I the DM, I'd probably penalize the fiend's save since a True Name was used).

@Pyrotechnical going as far as demon true names is a bit off the left field.

@Pyrotechnical awesome. More Q&A is always good. I'll see you over there. Let's build this bloody knowledge base.

You might want to link your followup question (What happens to the souls of non-evil creatures when they reach their aligned outer plane?) right in this answer, not just in comments.

Scrying has two viable targets: creatures and locations.
The Scrying spell allows to target a creature

You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you.

or a location

Instead of targeting a creature, you can choose a location you have seen before as the target of this spell. When you do, the sensor appears at that location and doesn't move.

Since a dead creature is an object and not a creature in game terms, Scrying automatically fails, since the target is not viable, but if you have seen the location where the corpse lies, you can cast Scrying targeting that location

There's a step missing in the last paragraph. but if you have seen the location where the corpse lies and know the corpse is there, you can cast[...] — the question doesn't imply the caster knows the creature is dead.

Answer: A dead creature is immune to effects that force Wisdom saves
Is a corpse an object? And if it is, is it also a (dead) creature?
I contend that it is both, while other answers here say (or once said) that it is an object, only.  Either way, your scrying spell will fail.  If a corpse is an object, only, it is not a legitimate target for the scrying spell.  If, as I believe, a dead creature is still a creature, then scrying can target a dead creature, because it targets creatures and locations.  However, even if a dead creature is a legitimate target, the spell still fails.  Scrying says:

You can see and hear a particular creature you choose that is on the same plane of existence as you. The target must make a Wisdom saving throw, which is modified by how well you know the target and the sort of physical connection you have to it.

Although the dead creature is a creature, it is also an object - and objects are immune to anything that provokes a Wisdom save:

Objects always fail Strength and Dexterity saving throws, and they are immune to effects that require other saves.

Thus, your scrying spell first acquires the dead creature as a legitimate target, then provokes a Wisdom save to which the creature is immune, and finally fails with all the consequences of the target having made the save, including that you cannot use the spell on it again for 24 hours.  Therefor, even if the creature is later returned from the dead, it is still protected for a day from any of your subsequent attempts at casting scrying.

Commentary: Is a dead creature both an object and a creature?
We have a question about whether or not a corpse is an object.  The accepted and most-highly-upvoted answer there asserts that a corpse is an object, but notably it also says (in comments) that a corpse is still a creature.
In that question, what OP really wants to know is "Can I use animate object on a corpse?"  And the consensus there is yes, because a corpse is an object.  But the accepted answer does not claim that a corpse is not a creature.  In fact, of the currently six answers there, only one claims that a corpse is not a creature, and that one has the lowest score of any of the answers.
Frustratingly, this very question is cited in many, many answers on this site as the touchstone that "corpses are not creatures", when in fact nearly all votes on the question itself do not agree with that claim.  On this page's question (What happens when you Scry a dead creature?), Eddymage says that the spell fails because 'a corpse is not a creature, it's an object' and cites that question as his proof.  Others answers here formerly did so.
AnnaAg simply asserts that a corpse is not a creature, but doesn't cite the question.
The reason for this common misunderstanding of the oft-cited question appears to be either / or thinking, or what is also known as a 'false dichotomy'.  Some people reason (I think incorrectly) that if a corpse is an object (which it is), then it cannot also be a creature.  But nothing in the 5e rules says that a thing cannot belong to two (or more) targeting categories, and in this case I believe there are examples of things that are both creatures and objects (although, as Matthieu points out we have a question about that, too; the accepted answer there is that suggested examples are not in two different categories, but not that they cannot be in two different categories for a fundamental rules reason).
We know, for example, that a dead goblin is an object, because it can be picked up and used as an improvised weapon.  But we also know that a dead goblin is simultaneously a creature, because it can be the target of spells like revivify, raise dead, resurrection, and true resurrection, all of which do not target objects, but do target creatures.
Those aforementioned spells use the phrases, respectively, "a creature that has died", "a dead creature", "a dead creature", and "a creature that has been dead".  As such, they make it clear that it is possible to be both dead and a creature at the same time1.
The rules also occasionally refer to "living creatures", such as in the text of the bag of devouring.  The phrase 'living creature' would be redundant and unnecessary if a creature ceased to be a creature when it died2.
Another kind of creature that appears (at least to me) to be simultaneously a creature and an object is a petrified creature3.

Footnotes
1 Those who object to the idea that a corpse is both a creature and an object sometimes do it on a linguistic basis, claiming that [dead creature] is its own targeting category, a separate entity, and that it is not simply a sub-category of creature.  We see this claim made by Slagmouth in their accepted answer to the aforementioned Is there anything that is simultaneously a creature and an object? and also made by Jeremy Crawford:

In a D&D rule, all the words work together. For example, targeting "a creature" is different from targeting "a creature that has died within the last minute."

There are three problems with this.  First, while it supports the idea that "a corpse is not a creature" (because it posits that [a creature that died within the last minute] is explicitly not a subcategory of [a creature]), it undercuts the premise of why a corpse is not a creature.  If you are making the argument that 'a corpse is an object and therefor cannot be a creature', you are relying on the premise that categories are mutually exclusive, that something cannot be both [a creature] and [an object].  By saying that revivify doesn't target a specific subset of [a creature], it instead targets [a creature that died within the last minute], you are admitting that a corpse is simultaneously both [an object] and [a creature that died within the last minute].  You are saying that something can belong to two targeting categories at the same time.  With that admission, then, what is the argument for 'a corpse cannot be a creature?' If not based on a premise of mutual exclusion, what is it based on?  If you are Jeremy Crawford, of course, you can just declare it as fiat:

A corpse is an object. An unconscious creature is a creature.

But since that is not an official rules statement, RAW we still don't have anything that explicitly says a dead creature is not a creature.
The second thing wrong with this linguistic defense ('revivify et al don't actually target creatures') is that is not how the rules in 5e are actually written or otherwise interpreted in general.
When the spell targeting rules are presented, they say:

A spell's description tells you whether the spell targets creatures, objects, or a point of origin for an area of effect (described below).

They don't say 'a target can be any combination of words, because all the words work together, for example, some spells target "a creature" and others target "a creature that has died in the last minute" and those are two completely independent things'.
When my warlock uses eldritch blast on a zombie, I don't expect the DM to say, "the zombie isn't a [creature], it's an [undead creature] and those are two separate and unrelated categories".  And yet the linguistic argument says that [dead creature] is not a subset of [creature].  So either [undead creature] is also not a subset of creature, because 'all the words work together', or the '[dead creature] means object' argument is just special pleading.
When the Sage Advice Compendium receives the question:

What does “melee weapon attack” mean: a melee attack with a weapon or an attack with a melee weapon?

Do they answer, "Actually, all the words work together, it is irreducibly a 'melee weapon attack'?  No, they answer:

It means a melee attack with a weapon. Similarly, “ranged weapon attack” means a ranged attack with a weapon.

because the 5e rules function with categories and sub-categories; within the category "attacks" there is a subcategory "melee attacks" and within that there is a subcategory that is "melee weapon attacks" - but "melee weapon attacks" is not a subcategory of "weapon attacks" and "weapon attacks" is not a subcategory of attacks.  These categories form the basis of rules and rulings and are a basic part of the structure of 5e.
Finally, the third thing wrong with this linguistic defense is that it is not how the rules work surrounding dead creatures specifically.  The spell raise dead says:

You return a dead creature you touch to life, provided that it has been dead no longer than 10 days. If the creature's soul is both willing and at liberty to rejoin the body, the creature returns to life with 1 hit point.

Even granting the [dead creature] targeted with "you return a dead creature you touch to life" is an independent linguistic category, and not a sub-category of creature, all we need to do is read the next sentence, which twice refers to the target as "the creature", and not as "the [dead creature]", as you would have to do if it was not in fact a creature.  Raise dead then goes on to list which conditions and persistent effects are removed from the creature by the spell and which remain after it has been restored to life.  Although not part of the spell description, errata adds that the spell further removes a single level of Exhaustion.  Philosophically, how were all the conditions that persisted after death and raising kept track of?  What makes more sense - for the corpse to have ceased to be a creature, and then for the same body to be used in the creation of a new never-existed before creature that just happens to be exactly the same as the old, including having many of the same conditions as the old creature did at the time of its death?  Or for the body to continue to be the same creature throughout the process, with the conditions active while alive, latent or suppressed while dead, and then re-activated upon raising? (Full disclosure: I think the second sounds more reasonable, in a game-entity sense)
2 Jeremy Crawford was asked for the definition of 'living creature', given that there are game entities like golems, devils, and animated tables.
First he said that

In D&D, "living creature" means a creature that isn't dead, regardless of the creature's type.

Note that this would mean that (1) undead creatures are living creatures and (2) if a corpse is an object, only, then a living creature is any creature.  'A creature that isn't dead' is any creature - because by his previous definition there is no such thing as 'a creature that is dead' (it's a null category).
Then he quickly added that the term "living creature" is almost never used in the rules, where it is it is sometimes accidental, and even when it is intentional it has 'no special meaning'.  'No special meaning' would make sense if there was indeed no such thing as a dead creature, if every creature was a living creature.
But then, less than 30 minutes later, he said that "living creature" is used intentionally in the description of the bag of devouring so that it is understood that:

The effect isn't triggered if you put the arm of a corpse into the bag, for instance.

By "the effect", he means

When part of a living creature is placed in the bag, as happens when someone reaches inside it, there is a 50 percent chance that the creature is pulled inside the bag.

So, he is saying that 'living creature' is used intentionally so that we understand that the arm of a corpse will not trigger the bag to pull inside the entire body.  But if we know that a corpse is not a creature, why do we need the special reminder here from a word that has no special meaning?
For my own part, I think the term 'living creature' is very useful, as it helps us distinguish creatures with a metabolism from dead creatures, but also from "once-living creatures" (undead) and "non-living creatures" (constructs).
3 As Matthieu rightly points out, nowhere is it stated that a petrified creature is an object.  That is largely my personal assessment based on the characteristics of a petrified creature being like the characteristics of an object.  But then, I don't think that the rules provide a comprehensive definition of what an object is, so I prefer a functional definition.  In any event, defending this point would take us too far off track, and it is not central to my argument, so I am happy to concede it to anyone that doesn't agree.

The scales have fallen from my eyes...

You make a good point, the question we linked does not, in fact, assert that corpses are not creatures. I do not think your point is as clear-cut as you make it to be though. A non-official tweet from Crawford actually shows that the intent was to have corpses not be creatures anymore. Moreover, the terms of "a dead creature" do not necessarily point out to the corpse still being a creature, and may instead just designate a specific kind of object : if that is the point of this sentence, I do not see any clearer way to express it.

You did change my point of view on this issue though, it now seems to me that whether or not creature and object are exclusive is instead ambiguous. See this FAQ for more accurate discussions regarding this topic.

"Another kind of creature that is simultaneously a creature and an object is a petrified creature." is there a rule somewhere that enforces this? I haven't found anything that says that a petrified creature is an object.

@Matthieu Re: "You did change my point of view on this issue though" - That is a pretty high complement, thank you. Also thank you for the Q&A about simultaneous creatures and objects - I had seen it previously but forgot about it and did not find it in preparing this answer.  As far as my claim that petrified creatures are objects - they sure act like it!  But no, there is not an explicit statement of that AFAIK, so that is better edited. W/rt Crawford, besides being unofficial, his tweets on the subject are contradictory

You get a bounty for attempting to correct one of the most egregious false dichotomies on this particular stack. Your effort is appreciated.

I see a big flaw here: I believe that the correct way is to consider "dead creature", "a creature that has died" and the others as objects, not creatures with a particular condition.

@Eddymage Yes, they are objects - it is my contention that they are also creatures.  If you don't think they are creatures, then you have to explain how the four spells listed can work on objects even though they don't say they target objects.  One way is to say "dead creature really means object", but to me that seems like it should count as a Hidden Rule.  YMMV.

@Matthieu Now edited to reflect your comments.

No, I mean that they are only objects, not objects and creature at the same time. They are objects called "dead creature". If they are creatures, they can be targeted also by healing spells: what happens then? There is no dual principle here.

@Eddymage I understand the argument that 'they are objects called "dead creature"' - I am even sympathetic to that argument and find it reasonable.  I just don't think it is RAW.  Nowhere do the rules say that dead creatures are only objects.  As far as healing spells, IMO they can target dead creatures.  They successfully target them, and then fail to restore hp, because the rules on healing say "A creature that has died can't regain hit points until magic such as the revivify spell has restored it to life."

@Kirt yeah, I made a bad example.. let's say then Fireball, or Magic Missile. The former is interesting, since it has different effects on creatures and on inflammable objects. I agree that considering them as object may be not completely RAW, but I do not really believe that they can be considered also creatures.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

If the categories "creature" and "object" aren't mutually exclusive, when isn't a creature an object?

@sptrashcan Unclear - can a giant pick up a live goblin and use it as an improvised weapon?  Personally, I don't think there is a definition of object RAW, but if we use the one most people do, it includes that objects are inanimate.  So one answer could be that a creature is not also an object so long as it is animate.

@Trish edited, in particular with regard to my claims about your answer

Can you Eldritch Blast a door?
To some people, the answer is "clearly no, the spell says it targets creatures, and a door is not a creature".  Similarly, can you use it to determine if someone is faking being dead?  If you cast Eldritch Blast on someone who has cast Feign Death, does it fail to fire if and only if they are actually dead?
To other people, Eldritch Blast is a spell that creates beams of force that fire out from your hand.  The description covers its typical use - to attack creatures - and leaves other uses up to the DM's adjudication.
So Eldritch Blast in this case can be used to blast a door (doing force damage), or a corpse, or whatever else.
I thought I asked about Scrying
Now, in this case, the Scrying spell describes two uses - scrying on a creature and on a location.  You can treat this as an exact hard limitation on how the spell works.
Or you can say "corpses of creatures are very creature-like".  And as a DM, you can determine how scrying works in that case.  Maybe it doesn't work and the caster learns no information.  Maybe it doesn't work right, and you get a hazy view of where the corpse is.  Maybe it tries to target the soul of the departed, which hangs around the corpse for a period of time before leaving to another plane (which is why lower level resurrection magic is time limited).
As a general rule, if you do allow such flexibility, I'd gate it behind an arcana check and a casting attribute check.  The arcana check is if a PC knows what could possibly happen when you violate the strict formula of a spell, and the casting attribute check might cover how well the spellcaster handles the "warped behavior" of the spell used "off-book".

Related: Can you prevent players using cantrips to tell whether a creature is disguised as an object?

I like this "Rule of Fun" based answer. :)

I think this is a great practical use answer. I also like it because it's one of the only answers that doesn't attempt to claim community consensus is RAW (when the consensus exists exactly because there is no RAW text to support that stance), which is misleading and below the standard of quality one would expect here.

The spell fails
A dead creature is not a creature anymore, it's an object. Scrying doesn't allow an object as a target, just a creature or location.
As to:

What, if anything, do you learn about their location and state?

Well, assuming you don't already know the creature is dead, you do learn that they're not a valid target for Scrying - and being dead is one of the possibilities why, although not the only one.

Other than the Improvised Weapons text, which confirms that a dead goblin can be treated as an object, is there an official source of text you're referencing that claims a dead creature stops being a creature? Two things can be true at once, and Improvised Weapons makes no claims of exclusivity. Being able to use a thing as another thing doesn't mean it stops being that thing - see Hoopaks, which can be used as martial ranged weapons, but continue to be melee weapons for any effects that melee weapons qualify for.

The spell fails...
Whether or not a "dead creature" is still technically a creature or not (and whether or not "creature" and "object" are exclusive or can coexist in a single entity) does not seem to have a clear cut answer (see this FAQ).
However, in any case, the corpse is still an object, and as such it is immune to Wisdom saving throws (thanks to Kirt's answer for pointing that out). So with the rules as written, you shouldn't be able to benefit from the effects of the spell, and it should fail.
... but how does it fail?
This Q&A treats the topic in-depths, but the overall answer is that (optional rules aside) your DM decides. This means that whether or not you learn why the spell failed, how much you learn about this, and even if you waste your spell slot or not is in your DM's hands.
Ask your DM
For this kind of unusual situation with no strict rules, it is best to ask your DM about how they would handle this situation beforehand. This will both allow them to think about it before it hits them during play, and avoid potential frustration on your end in case your DM rules this wastes a spell slot or gives less intel than you expected.
